# How to write regexp?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

how to write regexp in Jquery

i.e. `Var regexp = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;`

if there is any syntax to write the expression..

can any one help me, how to write and if u know any useful site share with meee..

Comment: depends how do you want to use it??

Comment: @what is your requirement , or its just for learning purpose?

Comment: The syntax for regexp remains the same, I  think there is no such distinction for Jquery. You can Google and number of results can be found, like this one - http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either write

```
var pattern = /abc/[modifiers];
```

or

```
var pattern = new Regex("abc",[modifiers]);
```